# My jQuery should be removing class but it isn't... thoughts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function activities() {

  // Shows info icon on hover //
  $(function hover() {
    $('.activity-img').hover(function() {
      $('.info-icon', this).stop().animate({'opacity': 0.7});
      $('h3', this).stop().animate({'color': 'white'});
    }, function() {
      $('.info-icon', this).stop().animate({'opacity': 0});
      $('h3', this).stop().animate({'color': 'black'});
    });
  });

  // reveals information on activity that is clicked //
  var activityId;
  var currentCopy;

  $(function activityImg() {
    $('.activity-img').on('click', function() {
      activityId = $(this).attr('data-activity');
      $('.activity-img').delay(500).fadeOut();
      $('#activity-copies').css('display', 'block');
      $('#' + activityId).addClass('open-copy').delay(1500).fadeIn();
    });
  });

  $(function activityCopy() {
    $('.close').on('click', function() {
      $('#' + activityId).removeClass('open-copy').fadeOut();
      $('.activity-copy').removeClass('open-copy');
      currentCopy.removeClass('open-copy');
      $('.activity-img').delay(500).fadeIn();
      $('#activity-copies').css('display', 'none');
    });
  });

  // allows navigation through activity info slides //

  $(document).ready(function navCopies()  {
    
    $('.arrow-next').click(function() {
      currentCopy = $('.open-copy');
      var nextCopy = currentCopy.next();

      if(nextCopy.length === 0) {
        nextCopy = $('.activity-copy').first();
      }
      
      currentCopy.hide().removeClass('open-copy');
      nextCopy.show().addClass('open-copy');

    });

    $('.arrow-prev').click(function() {
      var currentCopy = $('.open-copy');
      var prevCopy = currentCopy.prev();

      if(prevCopy.length === 0) {
        prevCopy = $('.activity-copy').last();
      }
      
      currentCopy.hide().removeClass('open-copy');
      prevCopy.show().addClass('open-copy');

    });

  });
```

```css
/*\-------------- HOLIDAY IDEAS --------------\*/

#activities-page h1 {
    width: 360px;
}

#activities-page {
    background-color: #c1f4f3;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

#activities {
    width: 900px;
    height: 840px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fefffa;
    position: relative;
}

.activity-img {
    width: 280px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px single lightgrey;
    border-radius: 2px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.activity-img h3 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.activity-copy {
    width: 920px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fefffa;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

.activity-imgs-3 {
    width: 1500px;
    height: auto;
    padding: ;
    margin: ;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.activity-imgs-4 img {
    width: 500px;
}

.info-icon {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#activities [data-activity = 'beaches'] {
    background-image: url('http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/beach_zpsec4dcc80.jpg');
    background-color: blue;
}
#activities [data-activity = 'bussana'] {
    background-image: url('http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/bussana_zpsb30c7bb1.jpg');
    background-position: left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #abe0da;
}
#activities [data-activity = 'cycleway'] {
    background-image: url('http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/cycleway_zps39041c18.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #20D1AC;
}
#activities [data-activity = 'whalewatch'] {
    background-image: url('http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/whale_zpsacf8b16f.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
#activities [data-activity = 'cervo'] {
    background-image: url('http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/cervo_zps345b3550.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
#activities [data-activity = 'la-mortola'] {
    background-image: url('http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/lamortola_zps47eee73a.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: red;
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-prev, .arrow-next {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #5956d0;
}

.arrow-next {
    float: right;
}

#activity-copies {
    width: 940px;
    height: 780px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}

.open-copy {
    display: block;
}

.activity-copy {
    width: 940px;
    height: 780px;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#activity-imgs-3 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 395px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 black;
    -box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 black;
}

.activity-copy h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.activity-copy p {
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 0;
}

#activity-imgs-3 .slides {
    width: 2080px;
    height: 395px;
    display: block;
}

#activity-imgs-3 .slides .slide {
    width: 500px;
    height: 395px;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}

#activity-imgs-3 .slides .slide img {
    width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id='activities'>
                <div data-activity='beaches' class='activity-img'>
                    <h3>SANDY BEACH</h3>
                    <img class='info-icon' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/information_icon-32_zpsa978bbe7.png'>
                </div>
                <div data-activity='bussana' class='activity-img'>
                    <h3>BUSSANA VECCHIA</h3>
                    <img class='info-icon' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/information_icon-32_zpsa978bbe7.png'>
                </div>
                <div data-activity='cycleway' class='activity-img'>
                    <h3>PISTA CICLOPEDONALE DELLA RIVIERA DEI FIORI</h3>
                    <img class='info-icon' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/information_icon-32_zpsa978bbe7.png'>
                </div>
                <div data-activity='whalewatch' class='activity-img'>
                    <h3>WHALEWATCH IMPERIA</h3>
                    <img class='info-icon' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/information_icon-32_zpsa978bbe7.png'> 
                </div>
                <div data-activity='cervo' class='activity-img'>
                    <h3>DAY TRIP TO CERVO</h3>
                    <img class='info-icon' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/information_icon-32_zpsa978bbe7.png'>
                </div>
                <div data-activity='la-mortola' class='activity-img'>
                    <h3>HANSBURY BOTANIC GARDENS</h3>
                    <img class='info-icon' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/information_icon-32_zpsa978bbe7.png'> 
                </div>
                <div id='activity-copies'>
                    <div id='beaches' class='activity-copy'>
                        <img class='close' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/1417929089_basics-22-48_zpsb099028b.png'>
                        <img class='arrow-next' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/4c8862a3-482f-4d76-80a4-ba2d0c5ed2bb_zpsf25e24fe.png'>
                        <img class='arrow-prev' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/1417929185_basics-05-128arrowprev-white_zps971b538a.png'>
                        <h2>Beaches</h2>
                        <div id='activity-imgs-3'>
                            <ul class='slides'>
                                <li class='slides'><img src=''></li>
                                <li class='slides'><img src=''></li>
                                <li class='slides'><img src=''></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur imperdiet elementum lacus, quis dignissim turpis pretium id. Nam non enim at diam tincidunt porttitor non id enim. Nulla ut lorem nec velit egestas eleifend. Curabitur pretium, dolor nec sollicitudin tempus, lectus nulla fermentum est, ornare aliquam ex leo id sapien. Praesent malesuada tincidunt nunc sed sodales. Fusce ac hendrerit ante. Vivamus congue in diam egestas interdum. Aliquam lobortis magna quis hendrerit suscipit. Maecenas sagittis, diam a finibus pulvinar, odio urna placerat risus, ac vehicula quam velit sed sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam quis augue lacus. Vivamus a finibus risus. Morbi sollicitudin eros id egestas commodo. Aenean vulputate, mi quis scelerisque lobortis, lacus eros malesuada massa, et dapibus purus est ac urna.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id='bussana' class='activity-copy'>
                        <img classs='close' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/1417929089_basics-22-48_zpsb099028b.png'>
                        <img class='arrow-next' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/4c8862a3-482f-4d76-80a4-ba2d0c5ed2bb_zpsf25e24fe.png'>
                        <img class='arrow-prev' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/1417929185_basics-05-128arrowprev-white_zps971b538a.png'>
                        <h2>Bussana Vecchia</h2>
                        <div id='activity-imgs-3'>
                            <ul class='slides'>
                                <li class='slides'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos'></li>
                                <li class='slides'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos'></li>
                                <li class='slides'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos'></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur imperdiet elementum lacus, quis dignissim turpis pretium id. Nam non enim at diam tincidunt porttitor non id enim. Nulla ut lorem nec velit egestas eleifend. Curabitur pretium, dolor nec sollicitudin tempus, lectus nulla fermentum est, ornare aliquam ex leo id sapien. Praesent malesuada tincidunt nunc sed sodales. Fusce ac hendrerit ante. Vivamus congue in diam egestas interdum. Aliquam lobortis magna quis hendrerit suscipit. Maecenas sagittis, diam a finibus pulvinar, odio urna placerat risus, ac vehicula quam velit sed sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam quis augue lacus. Vivamus a finibus risus. Morbi sollicitudin eros id egestas commodo. Aenean vulputate, mi quis scelerisque lobortis, lacus eros malesuada massa, et dapibus purus est ac urna.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id='cycleway' class='activity-copy'>
                        <img class='close' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/1417929089_basics-22-48_zpsb099028b.png'>
                        <img class='arrow-next' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/4c8862a3-482f-4d76-80a4-ba2d0c5ed2bb_zpsf25e24fe.png'>
                        <img class='arrow-prev' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/1417929185_basics-05-128arrowprev-white_zps971b538a.png'>
                        <h2>Pista ciclopedonale della Riviera dei Fiori</h2>
                        <div id='activity-imgs-3'>
                            <ul class='slides'>
                                <li class='slides'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos'></li>
                                <li class='slides'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos'></li>
                                <li class='slides'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos'></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur imperdiet elementum lacus, quis dignissim turpis pretium id. Nam non enim at diam tincidunt porttitor non id enim. Nulla ut lorem nec velit egestas eleifend. Curabitur pretium, dolor nec sollicitudin tempus, lectus nulla fermentum est, ornare aliquam ex leo id sapien. Praesent malesuada tincidunt nunc sed sodales. Fusce ac hendrerit ante. Vivamus congue in diam egestas interdum. Aliquam lobortis magna quis hendrerit suscipit. Maecenas sagittis, diam a finibus pulvinar, odio urna placerat risus, ac vehicula quam velit sed sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam quis augue lacus. Vivamus a finibus risus. Morbi sollicitudin eros id egestas commodo. Aenean vulputate, mi quis scelerisque lobortis, lacus eros malesuada massa, et dapibus purus est ac urna.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id='whalewatch' class='activity-copy'>
                        <img class='close' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/1417929089_basics-22-48_zpsb099028b.png'>
                        <img class='arrow-next' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/4c8862a3-482f-4d76-80a4-ba2d0c5ed2bb_zpsf25e24fe.png'>
                        <img class='arrow-prev' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/1417929185_basics-05-128arrowprev-white_zps971b538a.png'>
                        <h2>Whalewatch Imperia</h2>
                        <div id='activity-imgs-3'>
                            <ul class='slides'>
                                <li class='slides'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos'></li>
                                <li class='slides'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos'></li>
                                <li class='slides'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos'></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <p>The biologically teaming coastline of the Riviera means whale watching excursions are frequently made in the summer period. People of all ages enjoy this activity and it certainly makes for a quirky alternative to the aquarium. <a href='http://www.whalewatchimperia.it/index.php/en/whale-watching/trip'>Whalewatch Imperia</a> provide a regular boat service that picks up passengers from Sanremo, Imperia and Bordghera. Sitings of fin or sperm whales are successful for a great deal of the trips, but if there is no sighting during your trip, your ticket remains valid for another trip. Other creatures such as dolphins, rays and turtles are regularly spotted, and whatever happens you’re almost certain to spot something. There is generally a buzz of excitement on these trips and people are friendly. During the cruise out to sea your emotions melt away and there is little more relaxing than the feel of the cool wet air on a hot summer’s day.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id='cervo' class='activity-copy'>
                        <img class='close' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/1417929089_basics-22-48_zpsb099028b.png'>
                        <img class='arrow-next' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/4c8862a3-482f-4d76-80a4-ba2d0c5ed2bb_zpsf25e24fe.png'>
                        <img class='arrow-prev' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/1417929185_basics-05-128arrowprev-white_zps971b538a.png'>
                        <h2>Day trip to Cervo</h2>
                        <div id='activity-imgs-3'>
                            <ul class='slides'>
                                <li class='slides'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos'></li>
                                <li class='slides'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos'></li>
                                <li class='slides'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos'></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur imperdiet elementum lacus, quis dignissim turpis pretium id. Nam non enim at diam tincidunt porttitor non id enim. Nulla ut lorem nec velit egestas eleifend. Curabitur pretium, dolor nec sollicitudin tempus, lectus nulla fermentum est, ornare aliquam ex leo id sapien. Praesent malesuada tincidunt nunc sed sodales. Fusce ac hendrerit ante. Vivamus congue in diam egestas interdum. Aliquam lobortis magna quis hendrerit suscipit. Maecenas sagittis, diam a finibus pulvinar, odio urna placerat risus, ac vehicula quam velit sed sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam quis augue lacus. Vivamus a finibus risus. Morbi sollicitudin eros id egestas commodo. Aenean vulputate, mi quis scelerisque lobortis, lacus eros malesuada massa, et dapibus purus est ac urna.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id='la-mortola' class='activity-copy'>
                        <img class='close' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/1417929089_basics-22-48_zpsb099028b.png'>
                        <img class='arrow-next' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/4c8862a3-482f-4d76-80a4-ba2d0c5ed2bb_zpsf25e24fe.png'>
                        <img class='arrow-prev' src='http://i1334.photobucket.com/albums/w648/rwestanton/1417929185_basics-05-128arrowprev-white_zps971b538a.png'>
                        <h2>Hansbury Botanic Garden</h2>
                        <div id='activity-imgs-3'>
                            <ul class='slides'>
                                <li class='slide'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos/Flickr/A Nc Nd/467258563_fbf5c56221_b.jpg'></li>
                                <li class='slide'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos/Flickr/C/2/La Mortola.png'></li>
                                <li class='slide'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos/Flickr/A Nc Nd/11840672446_4a73a85cdc_h.jpg'></li>
                                <li class='slide'><img src='Content/Images/Promo photos/Flickr/A Nc Nd/467258563_fbf5c56221_b.jpg'></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur imperdiet elementum lacus, quis dignissim turpis pretium id. Nam non enim at diam tincidunt porttitor non id enim. Nulla ut lorem nec velit egestas eleifend. Curabitur pretium, dolor nec sollicitudin tempus, lectus nulla fermentum est, ornare aliquam ex leo id sapien. Praesent malesuada tincidunt nunc sed sodales. Fusce ac hendrerit ante. Vivamus congue in diam egestas interdum. Aliquam lobortis magna quis hendrerit suscipit. Maecenas sagittis, diam a finibus pulvinar, odio urna placerat risus, ac vehicula quam velit sed sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam quis augue lacus. Vivamus a finibus risus. Morbi sollicitudin eros id egestas commodo. Aenean vulputate, mi quis scelerisque lobortis, lacus eros malesuada massa, et dapibus purus est ac urna.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

For my website I have created a section that is dedicated to holiday ideas, which has a set of cover-pictures and information on activities holidayers might like. It is interactive, essentially like a gallery, and should work like this: the user clicks on a cover-picture; all the cover-pictures disappear and an information box for the corresponding activity is displayed; the user can either flick through all the boxes with different activity information or close their current box; once closed they can click on another cover-picture and it should repeat the first action described. But at this stage, the user is shown the last information box that they closed, and it shows every time they click on an arrow until the user has navigated through the activities and passed that box. 
I am assigning an 'open-copy' class which allows the user to navigate and I think it is somehow still attached.

In case my description isn’t enough, it should act like this page where you click on a product and it shows info on that product and allows you to flick through information on each product (minus some animation):
http://www.lesfleurs.ch/bouquets.php?lang=en&select_pays=110&monnaie=EUR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot in your close function to hide the element as well:

```
  $('.activity-copy').removeClass('open-copy').hide();
```

instead of

```
  $('.activity-copy').removeClass('open-copy');
```

Cause if you do not hide it as well, you will have on the next open click two elements with `display: block`. With the above code you hide all the elements on close and then you have just the right element with `display:block`.

Another thing:

```
currentCopy.removeClass('open-copy');
```

this line in your close function will fail if you open an info and close it without switching between the infos, cause `currentCopy` is undefined in that case.

Just do the following:

```
$('.open-copy').removeClass('open-copy');
```

This will remove all `open-copy classes` on close.

Comment: Thanks Twain, much appreciated! I found that there is no need to remove open-copy from currentCopy/open-copy. It works already with your first correction.